# Configuring Apache to Accept Specific Certificate from DOD CAC

Tags: apache, authentication, configuration, certificate, cac

I have Apache set up to require a DOD CAC in order to access the site.  On most DOD CAC there are actually 3 or 4 different certificates (ID, EMAIL, AUTH, etc).  I've noticed that for some websites, you need to pick the correct certificate or it won't grant access.  I've also been told that by 2020, all sites will require the AUTH certificate.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to only allow a specific certificate type - as currently, picking any certificate on the card with the proper PIN will grant access.

Comment: Following up on the comment about sites requiring the Authentication certificate by 2020. Do you of specific guidance or a publication that speaks to this requirement at either a high level or maybe even the technical details/implementation of the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Switch between the various certs on the CAC dialog, then viewing the cert properties, there is "Enhanced Key Usage" which contains "Smart Card Logon" on the auth cert.  This is not on the ID cert.

This post seems to address this with an Apache SSLRequire directive:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/200910.mbox/%3C20091015143102.GA4558@redhat.com%3E

I haven't gotten this to work yet, but I think with the help of this:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ssl.html

I am on the way.

Comment: Thanks.  "Smart Card Login" is part of the Signature cert though, so that's not quite gonna work.  It would eliminate using the ID or Encryption certs only.